# How to consistently distribute numbers on polyhedral dice to ensure maximal fairness?

Tags: distributions, dice

There are several regular solids made into dice (d6, d8, d10, d12, d20, d30).  You have to number each face starting at 1.  Given the imperfect nature of dice manufacture, you want to distribute the low numbers and high numbers on opposing faces to ensure that rolls will converge to the perfect average over time in case that the weight is not uniform throughout the solid.  Is there a consistent *ordering* that will ensure the fairest dice?

Looking at the icosahedron (d20), I'm wondering if each quintent of adjacent faces (there are 12 of them--one for each vertex) could be made to add up to the same number as a good heuristic to solve this problem.

Any thoughts?

[Edit: whuber pointed out that the above suggestion isn't possible.  Perhaps there is another method of numbering?]

Answer (score 2):

Each face is part of three quintets, whence its value will enter three times into the sum of all 12 quintets.  This implies the sum of all 12 quintets must equal

$$S = 3(1+2+\cdots + 20) = 630.$$

Since that's not a multiple of $12$, no solution is possible.

Comment: Hmm, you suggest it need to be a multiple of 12 because there are 12 quintets, but I don't see how this follows.  Each quintet shares 2 faces.  That should give some degree of leeway in arrangement.

Comment: If each quintet is to have the same total, then $630$ must be twelve times it.

Comment: Right, sorry, that must be right.  Yet it seems too unfortunate that there isn't an elegant solution.  So then the question would be can you alternate the use of opposing numbers in a path rotating around the icosahedron to balance the order of high numbers?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by that. Since the faces in the icosahedron occur in 10 opposite pairs, you certainly can label them $(1,20)$, $(2,19)$, and so on through $(10,11)$. An alternative way to formulate your question might be to ask the following. Given a numbering of the faces of an icosahedron, define the "imbalance" of any resting position of the icosahedron on one face to be the absolute difference between the sum on the 10 highest faces and the sum on the 10 lowest faces. What numbering(s) minimize the largest imbalance among the 20 resting positions? Can zero be achieved?

Comment: Probably due to this medium of the internet, I have trouble understanding your suggested phrasing.  Will revisit if clarity arrives.

Comment: I love your reasoning, actually.  I voted you up.  But I cannot check it as the accepted answer because this suggestion of using equal quintets was merely a suggestion.  There could be other answers.